# Difference between views and partitions with inherit

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have the same table structure for different countries in PostgresSQL and I'd like to have the same interface for all of them. As I understand there are two main ways to do this, with a View and with table inheritance.

First one would be something like:

`CREATE VIEW all_countries as first_country union second_country ...`

Second option would be:

`CREATE TABLE first_country INHERITS (all_countries)`

`CREATE TABLE second_country INHERITS (all_countries)`

And insert the data for each country to its table.

I'd like to understand what are the benefits and cons of each approach. For example in the second approach I can set some triggers to manage insertions automatically so the interface would also work with insertions. I suppose the approach with the view will be much slower as I'm forcing a union each time I need some info, even if it is only from one country. Is that right?

Thanks

Comment: When using a view, you need to re-create the view each time you add a new partition. You don't need to do that with inheritance. Also the optimizer can exclude partitions when you select from an inheritance table, this is also not possible when using the view.

Comment: While I'm agree with @a_horse_with_no_name (this seems a typical example of partitioning) but only if you have exclusive constraints for each child table (without them, the two approach may nearly be identical). Also, please note that [inheritance has](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) some [caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to summarize the statements from the comments and my own findings:
(please feel free to add/correct/detail statements here if you wish - I'll do so later on)
(I tried to prefer filling the *Pros* sides rather than the opposite *Cons* sides to avoid duplication and consistency. Also rather adding to *View Depends* than to *Pratitioning Depends*)

**I am assuming here a typical scenario, where we want to handle hard partitioned data with an abstracting view/master table!** so loosely based on the statement [partitioning overview](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW):

> *The benefits will normally be worthwhile only when a table would otherwise be very large. The exact point at which a table will benefit from partitioning depends on the application, although a rule of thumb is that the size of the table should exceed the physical memory of the database server.*

## Summary

*(of the below)*

- **biggest advantage of inheritance/partitioning** is that the **optimizer seems to work better** on the partitions if their check conditions are rather simple

  - so it's a bit sad that we have this "little value-adding" inheritance/partitioning feature where instead one could go for optimizing such `union all` views with its simpler existing `updatable view` functionality
- **another partitioning advantage is that *insert*, *update*, *delete* operations should work on partition master tables out of the box**
- **biggest disadvantage of inheritance/partitioning** is that **referential integrity** is not ensured easily (see details below) => so it basically can be a more low-level (storage/optimization) advantage, but with considerable high-level impact/effort/complexity :-/

## 1. abstraction via `views`

e.g.

```
create table men (...) ...
create table women (...) ...

create or replace view human as
          select  'male'   as gender,  m.*  from men m
UNION ALL select  'female' as gender,  w.*  from women w
-- (use "union all" to avoid "merge overhead")
```

### View Pro

- **more flexible to certain ddl structure changes** (e.g. rearrange columns)
- **dynamically computing/changing existing columns** (e.g. subtotals with window functions, string/maths functions, ...)
- *(see also partitioning Cons)*

### View Con

- *(see also partitioning Pros)*

### View Depends

- **both are not (directly) referentiable/indexable** since the indexes/foreign keys have to operate on the inheriting tables anyway
- **recreating the view when adding a new partition** (as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned) does not seem a big disadvantage to me

  - also mentioned [view alternative](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-ALTERNATIVES):

    > *However, the need to recreate the view adds an extra step to adding
    >   and dropping individual partitions of the data set. In practice this
    >   method has little to recommend it compared to using inheritance.*
- *(see also partitioning Depends)*

## 2. abstraction via `inheritance`/`partitions`

e.g.

```
create table human ( gender text, ...) ...  -- normally not containing 
                                            -- data/indexes (like a view)
create table men   ( gender text  check( gender = 'male'   ) ) inherits (human)
create table woman ( gender text  check( gender = 'female' ) ) inherits (human)
```

### Partitioning Pros

- general **insert, update and delete operations work automatically** as long as they do not violate the partition constraints
- **optimizable** by optimizer for rather **simple partitioning conditions**: [partitioning caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS)
- **concurreny/locking, bulk and maintenance operations** should generally work better here
- data **constraints**, e.g. uniqueness, can be enforced
- *(see also view Cons)*

### Partitioning Cons

- **not directly referencable** (e.g. via foreign key): [inheritance caveats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS)
- **referential integrity and column uniqueness is not ensured** since unique/primary indexes on the master are not possible/managed
- **automatically keeping rows inside the constraint-matching partition (after inserts/updates) is not supported** (one has to move the data via triggers/rules oneself)
- *(see also view Pros)*

### Partitioning Depends

- *(see also view Depends)*